# woocommerce Recent X commented products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'am looking for code in Woocommerce that allow me to display x items wth recent comments (reviews) added

simlar to [recent_products per_page="16" columns="4" orderby="rand"] shortcode but allowing to get post only with comments

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a shortcode for this.  You'd have to write some PHP.  The way that you can do this is:

```
    $number = 5; // Change as desired
    $comments = get_comments( array( 'number' => $number, 'status' => 'approve', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'post_type' => 'product' ) );

    if ( $comments ) {
        echo '<ul class="product_list_widget">';
        foreach ( (array) $comments as $comment ) {
            $_product = wc_get_product( $comment->comment_post_ID );
            $rating = intval( get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, 'rating', true ) );
            $rating_html = $_product->get_rating_html( $rating );
            echo '<li><a href="' . esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment->comment_ID ) ) . '">';
            echo $_product->get_image();
            echo $_product->get_title() . '</a>';
            echo $rating_html;
            printf( '<span class="reviewer">' . _x( 'by %1$s', 'by comment author', 'woocommerce' ) . '</span>', get_comment_author() );
            echo '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }
```

(Note: this code is lifted with modification from the WooCommerce plugin, "recent reviews" widget: `woocommerce/includes/widgets/class-wc-widget-recent-reviews.php`)

Answer (score 0):

This is untested, but something like this should work:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby' => 'comment_count',
        'order' => 'DESC'
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            if ( $post->comment_count < 1 ) continue;
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
```